# Canvas fabric.js: how to set the height correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I use fabris.js factories to work with objects canvas. If you change the height of a separate mouse or separate field - it works. If you change the mouse first, then field - to work with well-read false values.

Please help to fix.

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/millerish/fb7y8sfs/2/)

[A bug in the video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0d202oDNVw&feature=youtu.be)

Line 83, 84. Setting values:

```
canvas.getActiveObject().setHeight(parseInt(heightElInput.value));
canvas.getActiveObject().height = parseInt(heightElInput.value);
```

Comment: Somewhere you changing scaleY for the object that's why you have a bug. Insert this code after line 84 and it should work: canvas.getActiveObject().scaleY = 1; Also, you can you function setHeight, you don't need to use both of them

Comment: I never ask this value (scaleY). Only when you add(scaleY: 1). How can this be?

Comment: Did it fix your problem? You did ask for this change. Every time when you are using FabricJs controls for resize it will scale your object. You have to build you own logic for resizing. I mean you can use scale factor multiply by height and/or width and use this value as a new height and/or width and reset back scale factors to 1.

Comment: Thank you. The question is solved

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you changing scaleY for the object that's why you have a bug. Insert this code after line 84 and it should work: canvas.getActiveObject().scaleY = 1 - when you resize vertically, if horizontally - canvas.getActiveObject().scaleX = 1; Also, you can you function setHeight, you don't need to use both of them – Observer